# Bootstrap collapse

Tags: javascript, css, twitter, twitter-bootstrap

I've spent a few hours trying to get this bootstrap collapse plugin to work. I'm sorry if this question has been asked a bunch before but I've scoured this place for a suitable answer. Here is my html:

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>:(</title>
   <!-- Bootstrap -->
   <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>

 <body>
   <h1>Collapse!</h1>

  <a class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
     simple collapsible
  </a>

  <div id="demo" class="collapse in">
        <p>Hopefully this content will be collapsible!</p>
        <p>And this too!</p>
  </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".collapse").collapse()
});
</script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

This is also my first use of stackoverflow to ask a question, so excuse the fact that I don't know how to properly format my question. I just added in that little snippet of jquery in the hopes that it would somehow initialize the js elements on the page. Please help!

Comment: Place your java script code after including the jquery and bootstrap plugin.

Comment: A good Html structure follow the order like >>> 1. css file, 2. css inline code, 3. javaScript file, 4. javaScript inline code.

Comment: Changing the order of the scripts doesn't appear to help

Comment: @ Will Piers -> See, if you are using a javascript library and playing with it, you should call before your custom code.I'm sure it will work if there is no error in code.

Comment: also you forgot to put semicolon after `$(".collapse").collapse()`

Comment: @MohamedNavas: Semicolons are optional in JS in most cases, including this one. It's probably a better idea to stick with using them in case you run into one of the edge cases, but one-command functions are pretty safe either way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working version of your code http://jsbin.com/aximay/1/edit

Comment: Is it not the order of the JS? Are you getting any JS errors?

Comment: Try to check if the Css files and js files have the right path also check the console for errors

Comment: Now I've written everything in the same order that @bmscomp has it. I've written the exact same document as him, but I'm linking to bootstrap and jquery from different places than he is. I just got a fresh download of bootstrap this morning. So I don't understand why it's not working. Do you absolutely need to have the bootstrap-responsive.css?

Comment: Hey just check the code "bmscomp" done.There is no change in the code. also you should check what order he placed the javascript. you may check the error with google chrome. press F12 in Google Chrome and see if there is red mark on the right bottom side. click on that, now you can see the error produced.

Comment: Failed to load resource file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function bootstrap.min.js:6

Comment: no need for the bootstrap-responsive.css , for the first step try to use the CDN files, or see if Js is enables for your browser it may be the reason, because for me I tried every position possible for css and js files and it works for me. http://jsbin.com/ajujor/1/edit

Comment: this is where I got my jquery link https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide

Comment: download and include to your project

Comment: where do you recommend I get my jquery in the future?

Comment: if you are working online it's better to get from [CDN] it's faster (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js)

Comment: Ha ha.. I think the discussion going on the wrong way. have you checked the semicolon in your code. Also you can get the latest version of jquery online here http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js

Comment: haha it's all good now. I'm working fine at this point. I've used bootstrap for css stuff for a while but this i the first time I tried to use any of it's js stuff. I was just getting frustrated with it, but it was clearly just a jQuery problem

Answer (score 0):

I see that this question is a bit old,  but just an additional note.

It seems there is no need to use the Bootstrap data attributes AND the javascript. The [BS docs (see Usage)](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse) are not clear that these are distinct alternatives, but it works fine with either one independently (data attributes OR JS).